# check if UAC is enabled with VB6

Tags: vb6, registry, uac

is it possible to check if UAC is enabled with VB6 on win7 and vista?
i know it has to do with reading a value in the registry, i have see .net versions, but i need a vb6 sample code

thanks

Comment: Isn't the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/95510/how-to-detect-whether-vista-uac-is-enabled ? Or do you know the registry details already and just asking "how do I read the registry in VB6?"

Comment: that example is actually a .net vesion. i specifically dont know how to do it in vb6, thats why i wrote this one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[DevX.com](http://www.devx.com/vb2themax/Tip/19134) has an example of how to read the registry using VB6.

You'll have to add this constant: `Const HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE = &H80000002`...it's missing from the sample.

You'll want to read the `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System` key's  `EnableLUA` value.  1 == enabled.

There's also a decent example at [freevbcode.com](http://www.freevbcode.com/ShowCode.asp?ID=314).

Comment: will this example work with win7 & vista alike, am only testing on vista right now, as i don't have win7 yet

Comment: It's the same key on Win7 as Vista.